# Fortran: IF statement not working (although variables have correct value)

Tags: if-statement, fortran

```
    read(100,5) temp, a, charac    
  5 format(A11,i1,A7)

    read(100,*) b
    read(100,*) c
    read(100,*) d

    if ((a .ne. 0 .or. b .ne. 0 .or. c .ne. 0 &
         .or. d .ne. 0) .and. trim(charac) .ne. 'spline') then

      print *, 'Scenario A'

    else if ((a .ne. 0 .or. b .ne. 0 .or. c .ne. 0 &
              .or. d .ne. 0) .and. trim(charac) .eq. 'spline') then

      print *, 'Scenario B'

    else

      print *, 'Scenario C'

    end if
```

Input file:
    *---------------------------------------------------------------

```
My input file from which i am reading these looks as below:
      1      spline
      0
      0
      0
*----------------------------------------------------------------
```

what I want

```
scenario A is triggered if any of the integers a,b,c,d have a value of "1" and  input file not containing the word "spline"

scenario B is triggered if any of the integers a,b,c,d have a value of "1" and  input file contains the word "spline"

scenario C is triggered if all of the integers a,b,c,d have a value of "0" and  input file not containing the word "spline"
```

*---------------------------------------------------------------------

I was initially placing some other word in place of spline for Scenario A to trigger, but I require that Scenario A and C trigger if there is nothing written i.e. empty space.

This is the reason that I am using formatting in read, otherwise the read statement goes to the next line when it does not finds any character in that specific line.

I have tried printing the variables and the variables shows correct values to trigger Scenario B but it still triggers A

Comment: could you format your question a little bit and add a tag about what language it is?

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr Sorry.... its fortran90

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr If I print the values for variables then I get a=1, charac=spline. According to the if statement Scenario B should be triggered in this case, But it triggers scenario A instead.....

Comment: What is `temp`? Show the complete program.

Comment: The code is a mess, no wonder you have problems getting it right. I applied some formatting. You should also use `/=` and `==` instead of `.ne.` and `.eq.`.

Comment: @VladimirF am using temp to store the empty spaces before the integer "1" for a. There are empty spaces in the formatting of the input file that is being stored in temp.

Comment: That is very strange, you should not need it. Anyway, did you print the values of your variables to be sure they have the right value?

Comment: @VladimirF yes the variables have the right values. If I don't use temp then the formatting for integer i.e."i1" does not gets the value of 1. there are 11 spaces before the integer 1 there fore I stored them in temp and them provided the formatting for 1.

Comment: @VladimirF I have written an answer, This is working. Please forgive my sloppiness I am new to coding. If I don't use goto statement then the read statement keeps on reading to the next line if there is no character for "charac", by using end and goto,it doesnot goes to the next line searching for variable charac and stores the right values.

Comment: You could just read with `i12` directly without any `temp`. Or use the `x`,`tr` or `t` descriptors.

Comment: yes doing i12 works also... even when using the temp I was getting the correct values  for all the variables but the if statement was not triggering, I still dont know why. Doing it with end and goto works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 read(100,*,end=5)a,charac    
    5 go to 6

6   read(100,*)b
    read(100,*)c
    read(100,*)d

    if ((a .ne. 0 .or. b .ne. 0 .or. c .ne. 0 &
         .or. d .ne. 0) .and. trim(charac) .ne. 'spline') then

      print*, 'Scenario A'

    else if ((a .ne. 0 .or. b .ne. 0 .or. c .ne. 0 &
              .or. d .ne. 0) .and. trim(charac) .eq. 'spline') then

      print*, 'Scenario B'

    else

      print*, 'Scenario C'

    endif
```

Explanation: 
The problem that I was facing was that I wanted the code to work such that it reads values for an integer "a" and character "charac" from the same line. I wanted the code to go through different scenarios in case if the "charac" had specific value in the input file and in case if there is no input for "charac" i.e. the input line contains integer only and no character. 
What was going wrong was that in case if the input file had no character in that specific line, the read statement continues to read into the next line.

To avoid this I was using formatting to stop the read line after it has read certain number of characters, This is what is shown in my question. Doing it that way the if statement was not working properly, may be the inputs were not being read properly due to the formatting.

I did it the other way by using end statement in the read command and using go to command. So now the read statement ends at that line and I ask the code to go to the next read statement if it does not finds any input for charac.

This is the exact code that I am using:

```
read(100,*)curv,spanwise_spline
if (trim(spanwise_spline).eq.'spline')then
 go to 6
elseif (trim(spanwise_spline).ne.'spline')then
go to 7
endif

6 read(100,*)
7 read(100,*)thick_distr
read(100,*)
read(100,*)thick
read(100,*)
read(100,*)LE
```

Comment: You should try to explain what you changed and where was the error.

Comment: @VladimirF have a look at the code that I am using now.